# Selenium find element inside element

Tags: jquery, html, css, selenium, xpath

I'm using Selenium WebDriver and I have a table where it has many rows and columns. Each row has its own checkbox to select this row.
I need to choose checkbox which is in exact row. I'm trying

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[.='jared124']//[@type='checkbox']")
```

but it doesn't working
the html code is:

```
<tr class="even">
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ohrmList_chkSelectRecord_1239" 
             name="chkSelectRow[]" value="1239">
  </td>
  <td class="left">
    <a href="saveSystemUser?userId=1239">jared124</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about xpath following-sibling, preceding-sibling, parent and ancestor. It will help you to build xpath locators.
Try below:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'jared124')]/parent::tr/td[1]/input")
```

or you can click checkbox using its value:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='1239']")
```

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='1239']") working but not exactly what i needed, i want to find checkbox using 'jared124' element.

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'jared124')]/parent::tr/td[1]/input") get me no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: ("//td[.='jared124']/parent::tr/td[1]/input") is working, thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer using `xpath` locator

```
//a[text()='jared124']//preceding::input[@value='1239']
```

**Explanation of xpath:** Using `text` method find text as `jared124` along with `<a>` tag and then move ahead with `preceding` keyword to find the check box with `<input>` tag along with `value` attribute.

Comment: Hello Based on this line in your question. `I need to choose checkbox which is in exact row.`. . I guess you should accept my answer. Because I have provided you proper `xpath` along with checkbox label name.